# Deleting checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im very new to Javascript so any and all input would be welcomed.
I am having issues in creating a function used to delete selected checkboxes. I have tried numerous things but end up just deleting the entire function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Shopping List</title>
        <script>
            /*
            Create a shopping list program using javascript.  The page should have a text input, an “add” button, a “delete checked” button, and a list of items.  Each item should have a checkbox next to it.  If you fill out the text input and click” add,” it should add a list item to the end of the list.  If you check a box (or boxes) next to a list item then click “delete checked,” it should remove the list items that were checked.  Style the page using CSS.  
            */
            function addIt() {
                var list = document.getElementById("list"); //used to grab the parent level "list"
                var li = document.createElement("li"); //creates a "li" in the document
                var userTxt = document.getElementById("product"); //used to grab the user text input "product"
                var childText = userTxt.value; //returns the userTxt value and sets it equal to childText
                var childTextNode = document.createTextNode(childText); //creates a textNode in the document based on what the user entered in the "product" text field
                var chkBox = document.createElement("input"); //creates a new input based on the user input
                chkBox.type = "checkbox"; //creates a checkbox next to the user input from "product"

                //form the relationship
                li.appendChild(chkBox); //
                li.appendChild(childTextNode); //
                //attach to the parent element
                list.appendChild(li); //
                inputText.value = "";
                inputText.focus();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
            <input id="product" type="text" />
            <input type="button" id="Add" value="Add" onclick="addIt()" />
            <input type="button" id="Delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteIt()" />
            <ul id="list">
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" />Eggs</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're using an XHTML DOCTYPE but an HTML MIME type. If you want to use XHTML, you should probably add an XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) and use the correct MIME type (`application/xhtml+xml`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input in html (added name tag)

```
  <ul id="list">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name='food'>Eggs</input></li>
  </ul>
```

While adding (in addIt() add name to checkbox)

```
 chkBox.type="checkbox";                                 

 chkBox.name = 'food';
```

Now deleteIt function

```
function deleteIt(){
    var food = document.getElementsByName('food'); // get the checkbox
    for (i=0; i<food.length; i++) // loop through it
    {
    // if the current state is checked, unchecked and vice-versa
            if (food[i].checked) // if its checked
            {
            var remElm = food[i];   // element to be removed
        var list=document.getElementById("list"); // also li to be removed           
        food[i].nextSibling.nodeValue = ''; // Text value set to 
        remElm.parentNode.removeChild(remElm);
        ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
        ul.removeChild(li[i]);
            } else {       
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. what is the point of the input from "product" and chkBox.name="food";

Comment: also I inputed your code for the deleteIt function and it will delete the original "Eggs" but anything else that is entered it will not delete. Any insight would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to delete them as children of the parent wrapper.

Then you can use this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild

To delete the child as you pass it into the method

```
function deleteCheckbox(cbId){
  document.getElementById("content").removeChild(document.getElementById(cbId));
}
```

and in your html

```
<checkbox onclick="deleteCheckbox(id)">
```

That's assuming you know its ID. If you don't you can access it based on its order. I'm not entirely clear on which checkbox you're hoping to delete, but it's done the same way as you are already doing with adding a child, just in reverse :)

Comment: aww i think i was forgetting the (this) when i was trying it before. I will give it a shot and see if thats what i was doing wrong

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question... this won't help you here because you don't need a reference to the button itself... I thought you were clicking on the checkbox, then I re-read. However, you can access the checkbox as a child of your listItem.

Comment: ya it deletes the actual button itself and not the checkboxes.

Comment: right... so, just consider how you're currently adding it. You're making it a child of a listItem).  You can either delete the whole list item or just the checkbox (seems to make sense to lose the whole listItem. Look at the way all DOM objects see their children, that should quickly lead you to the answer as to how to remove any given child either by its ID or by its order in the branch.

Answer (score 0):

A generic `removeElement` function might be:

```
function removeElement(element) {
  if (element && element.parentNode) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
}

// Use example
removeElement(document.getElementById('someId'));
```